# Authentication for API & Python

Tags: python, api

I'm trying to get make an API for the first time and I've made my app but it says I have to do a local authentication with instructions here:

[Link to TDAmeritrade authentication](https://developer.tdameritrade.com/content/simple-auth-local-apps)

But it says I have to go on https://auth.tdameritrade.com/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri={URLENCODED REDIRECT URI}&client_id={URLENCODED Consumer Key}%40AMER.OAUTHAP where I plug in the "url encoded redirect uri" and "urlencoded consumer key" and I dont know how to get the URI. Let's say if I'm using local host 1111 do i just plug in "localhost:1111"? because that didnt work

Perhaps that doesn't even matter? because I was writing the following:

```
import requests
from config import consumer_key
#daily prices generator
endpoint = "https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/marketdata/{}/pricehistory".format("AAPL")

#parameters
import time
timeStamp=time.time()
timeStamp=int(timeStamp)
parameters = {'api_key':consumer_key,
             'periodType':'day',
             'frequencyType':"minute",
             'frequency':'5',
             'period':'1',
             'endDate':str(timeStamp+86400),
             'startDate':str(timeStamp),
             'extendedHourData':'true'}
#caller
stuff = requests.get(url = endpoint, params = parameters)

#reformater
lister = stuff.json()
lister
```

which returned "{'error': 'The API key in request query param is either null or blank or invalid.'}"

Comment: Please do not share images of code, but the code itself.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I am having the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TDA has some rules

> - timeStamp needs to be in milliseconds
> - Can only get past 31 days in minute format

There is also some format constraints.

```
frequenceType=minute --> then use periodType=day
frequencyType=daily  --> then use periodType=month
```